# Filter an object array based on certain conditions

Tags: javascript

How can I rewrite this in a cleaner way?

I have this function that takes a list of `contacts` of different types (are being called `relationships`.
If there are `contacts` of type `A` the list should be filtered to only include contacts of type `A`, otherwise, it should only include contacts of type `B`.

```
const getContactNames = () => {
  let filteredContacts = contacts.filter(c => c.relationship === 'A')
  if (!filteredContacts.length) {
    filteredContacts = contacts.filter(
      c => c.relationship === 'B'
    )
  }
  return filteredContacts.map(contact => getContactName(contact))
}
```

The `getContactName` function:

```
const getContactName = contact =>
  `${contact?.title || ''} ${contact?.firstName || ''} ${
    contact?.lastName || ''
  }`.trim()
```

`contact` object:

```
const contact = {title:"Mr", firstName:"test", lastName: "test", relationship: "B", address: "test", city:"NY", state:"NY"}
```

How can I rewrite the `getContactNames` function in a cleaner way?

Comment: Please clarify:  If `contactNames` contains *any* "type A" contacts then return all the "type B" contacts; then if there are no "type A" contacts then return nothing / an empty set?  Also, "... should only leave contacts of type B" - "leave" implies to delete all contacts except "typeB"  from `contactNames`.

Comment: Show the `contact` definition in the code. Without knowing that and how it one is  created an answer is guesswork. The chaining operator `?.` implies a `contact` contains other objects that may or may not be `contact` object(s).  Then defaulting the property to an empty string implies these properties may or may not be initialized upon creation.

Comment: @radarbob the `contacts` list can contain contacts of 4 different types, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.  If there are `contacts` of type `A` I want to remove all the other types and only get the ones with type `A`, If there are no type `A` contacts, I only want to get the type `B` contacts. If no type `A` and no type `B` then the list should return empty.
I have edited my question and added the `contact` object.

Comment: There is no `contact.type` property. I assume you mean `object.relationship` to be the type?

Comment: Yes, correct, I referred to `contact.relationship`

Comment: Your comment reply *I want to remove all the other types* Again, "remove" means "delete". I think I know you do not mean that. And also that there is no such thing as "type" anywhere in the code itself; the description and the actual code conflict. I'm being a pedantic pain just to show how precision, terminology, etc.  is so important to readers trying to evaluate correctness and suggest changes.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I have edited the question, I hope now it's clearer.

Comment: That `contact` object is not valid javascript. Is it a snippet from a JSON object? Are you unpacking the JSON to an  array of proper JS objects?  There is not enough context (code ) to tell how or if this works.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rewrite this in a cleaner way?

The `contact` object does all the work for itself: initializing properties, formatting name output. If some client code is doing something to an object's properties then it probably should be a method/function in that object.

```
function contact(fromJSON) {
  title:     fromJSON.title     || "",
  firstName: fromJSON.firstName || "",
  lastName:  fromJSON.lastName  || "", 

  contactName: function() { 
    return `${ this.title } ${ this.firstName } ${ this.lastName }`.trim()
  }
}
```

New contact objects are initialized with blank string. The chaining operator is not needed as there are no nested objects in `contact`

---

Filtering for "A else B" types. The point is avoiding nesting when practical which naturally makes reading and understanding easier.

Yes, filtering for "B"s may sometimes be unnecessary but I don't care. I love how clean, simple, and clear the code feels. If performance might be an issue, well, that's what testing is for.

```
// if there are no type "A" contacts, give me type "B"s
const getContacts = () => {
   let ContactsA = contacts.filter( c => c.relationship === 'A' )
   let ContactsB = contacts.filter( c => c.relationship === 'B' )
  
   return ContactsA.length ? ContactsA : ContactsB
}
```

---

Client code

```
const contacts = // array of contacts from JSON object
const AorBcontacts = getContacts()
AorBcontacts.forEach( x => console.log( x.contactName() ))
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll address the two functions independently. Since you've asked "how can I rewrite this in a cleaner way", I've assumed you're interested in the process of determining a cleaner way, not just the end result. So I've written out my thought process.

(By the way, in a few places I've said "I don't like X", which I'm using as a short hand for "I have an intuition that we can do better, but I haven't fully explored the tradeoffs, I'd like to try changing it and see if it's better". I acknowledge that what I personally like and don't like is irrelevant to you, but there are definitely times when intuition leads us to a new solution which we can objectively conclude is preferable.)

#### `getContactNames`

The first thing I would do is to write your code in English. This is the best way I know of to write readable code, because I'm good at assessing whether English is awkward.

```
function getContactNames() {
   // if there are any contacts with relationship A
   // use only the As
   // otherwise use only the Bs
   // return the contact names for whatever contacts you chose
}
```

I've noticed that you're filtering the list twice, but we don't have to. For a marginal performance improvement, and because I consider this to make the code simpler, I would suggest looping once instead (and assigning to the appropriate list in the loop).

```
function getContactNames() {
   const typeAContacts = [];
   const typeBContacts = [];
   // for each of the contacts, put them into the correct contact list
   // if there are any type A contacts, use those
   // otherwise, use the type B contacts
   // return the contact names for whatever contacts you chose
}
```

The next thing I'd like to address is that this method is doing two things (choosing the contact list; mapping to names). I'll split the method:

```
function getContactNames() {
   const filteredContacts = chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType(contacts);
   return filteredContacts.map(getContactName);
}

// This method name I chose is awkward, but it's a placeholder for now
function chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType(contacts) {
   const typeAContacts = [];
   const typeBContacts = [];
   // for each of the contacts, put them into the correct contact list
   // if there are any type A contacts, return those
   // otherwise, return the type B contacts
}
```

I wrote `filteredContacts.map(getContactName)` instead of `filteredContacts.map(contact => getContactName(contact))` because they are functionally equivalent but the former is more concise. It's a style preference though.

OK, I've finished with `getContactNames` and will now focus on the private `chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType` method:

```
function chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType(contacts) {
   const typeAContacts = [];
   const typeBContacts = [];
   contacts.forEach(contact => {
     if (contact.relationship === 'A') {
       typeAContacts.push(contact);
     } else if (contact.relationship === 'B') {
       typeBContacts.push(contact);
     }
   });
   return typeAContacts.length ? typeAContacts : typeBContacts;
}
```

Decisions like using the ternary expression and the format of the if/else should match whatever your project style guide specifies. Some teams may prefer you omit the curly braces on the one line if/else, or use switch. Other teams may disallow the use of ternary expressions, so you would need another if/else.

At this point, I don't like how long this is and may choose to split it:

```
function chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType(contacts) {
   const { B: typeBContacts, A: typeAContacts } = groupByRelationship(contacts);
   return typeAContacts.length ? typeAContacts : typeBContacts;
}

function groupByRelationship(contacts) {
   return contacts.reduce((all, one) => {
     all[one.relationship] = all[one.relationship] || [];
     all[one.relationship].push(one);
     return all;
   }, {});
}
```

Since `groupByRelationship` is very generic, I would extract it to a separate file and unit test it independently.

#### `getContactName`

I prefer the function syntax over anonymous functions. When debugging, this function is named, whereas the anonymous function assigned to a constant is not a named function. However, it's mostly a team preference thing. I'd say go with whatever is conventional in your context.

```
function getContactName(contact) {
  return `${contact?.title || ''} ${contact?.firstName || ''} ${
    contact?.lastName || ''
  }`.trim()
}
```

First, to English

```
function getContactName(contact) {
  // return the title, first name, and last name (if present) joined by spaces
}
```

I like to use filter/join for this sort of thing because it's closer to the English version:

```
function getContactName(contact) {
  // return the tile, first name, and last name
  const { title, firstName, lastName } = contact;
  const nameParts = [title, firstName, lastName];
  return nameParts
    // if present
    .filter(x => !!x)
    // joined by spaces
    .join(' ');
}
```

- `.filter(x => !!x)` is equivalent to `|| ''`
- `join(' ')` is equivalent to the `} ${` between the terms in the original code.

```
function getContactName(contact) {
  const { title, firstName, lastName } = contact;
  const nameParts = [title, firstName, lastName];
  return nameParts.filter(x => !!x).join(' ');
}
```

#### Putting it all together:

```
function getContactNames() {
   const filteredContacts = chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType(contacts);
   return filteredContacts.map(getContactName);
}

function chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType(contacts) {
   const { B: typeBContacts, A: typeAContacts } = groupByRelationship(contacts);
   return typeAContacts.length ? typeAContacts : typeBContacts;
}

function groupByRelationship(contacts) {
   return contacts.reduce((all, one) => {
     all[one.relationship] = all[one.relationship] || [];
     all[one.relationship].push(one);
     return all;
   }, {});
}
function getContactName(contact) {
  const { title, firstName, lastName } = contact;
  const nameParts = [title, firstName, lastName];
  return nameParts.filter(x => !!x).join(' ');
}
```

We now have some generic contact stuff and some thing specific to this code you're working on. I would extract `groupByRelationship` and `getContactName` into a separate contact utility, and leave `getContactNames` and `chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType` in the current spot. Also, since `chooseContactsOfOneMostAppropriateType` is now so short, I think we could inline it. Thus:

```
// main code
function getContactNames() {
   const { B: typeBContacts, A: typeAContacts } = groupByRelationship(contacts);
   const filteredContacts = typeAContacts.length ? typeAContacts : typeBContacts;
   return filteredContacts.map(getContactName);
}
```

```
// contactManagement.js (or something like that)
function groupByRelationship(contacts) {
   return contacts.reduce((all, one) => {
     all[one.relationship] = all[one.relationship] || [];
     all[one.relationship].push(one);
     return all;
   }, {});
}
function getContactName(contact) {
  const { title, firstName, lastName } = contact;
  const nameParts = [title, firstName, lastName];
  return nameParts.filter(x => !!x).join(' ');
}
```